# Creating object from a list by grouping on repeated information

Tags: c#, linq

Consider the `Customer` class below -

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

If I have a `List<Purchase>`, where `Purchase` is -

```
public class Purchase
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

and the list contains repeated customer related information like -

```
var list = new List<Purchase>
{
    new Purchase { CustomerId=1, CustomerName="Alice",  ProductName="CPU", Price=250 },
    new Purchase { CustomerId=1, CustomerName="Alice",  ProductName="RAM", Price=100 },
    new Purchase { CustomerId=1, CustomerName="Alice",  ProductName="HDD", Price=150 },
    new Purchase { CustomerId=2, CustomerName="Bob",    ProductName="RAM", Price=100 },
    new Purchase { CustomerId=2, CustomerName="Bob",    ProductName="SSD", Price=200 },
};
```

how can I create a list of `Customer` object from this list?

Comment: Using `.GroupBy` and  `.Select`? Show us your attempt

Comment: @Charlieface I'm really not very good with `LINQ`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With LINQ, you would want to use a [group by](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results) and then map the grouped results into your `Customer` model using a sub query:

```
var customerList = from p in list
            group p by new { p.CustomerId, p.CustomerName } into grp
            select new Customer() {
                Id = grp.Key.CustomerId,
                Name = grp.Key.CustomerName,
                Products = grp.Select(
                       prd => new Product() {
                           Name = prd.ProductName,
                           Price = prd.Price
                       }
                    ).ToList()
            };
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
var customerList = list.GroupBy(p => new { p.CustomerId, p.CustomerName })
    .Select(grp => new Customer() {
                Id = grp.Key.CustomerId,
                Name = grp.Key.CustomerName,
                Products = grp.Select(
                       prd => new Product() {
                           Name = prd.ProductName,
                           Price = prd.Price
                       }
                ).ToList()
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

First use `GroupBy` from `System.Linq` and then create new customer list using `Select`:

```
var customers = list.GroupBy(x => x.CustomerId)
   .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
   .Select(x => new Customer {
     Id = x.CustomerId,
       Name = x.CustomerName
   }).ToList();
 customers.ForEach(x => {
   x.Products = list.Where(t => t.CustomerId == x.Id)
   .Select(t => new Product {
     Name = t.ProductName,
       Price = t.Price
   }).ToList();
 });
```